# How to change domain.com to staging.domain.com in Ruby on Rails on Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, url, staging

We have a production website that is located at domain.com.
I would like it to be staging.domain.com. 
The website is written in Ruby on Rails, and it uses apache and passenger to deploy.
I have edited our etc/hots file to say

> (ip address) staging.domain.com

I have also edited the staging.domain.conf file in etc/apache2/sites-available and added it to sites-enabled. 
I edited the .conf file to say the following in both http and https:

> ServerName staging.domain.com
>
> ServerAlias staging.domain.com

I also updated the DNS records locally, and globally. 
However, when I go to staging.domain.com it redirects me to domain.com. 
Domain.com is hosted by another server and it reroutes me to this other server.
If I ping staging.domain.com I get the staging server. 
And when I go to ipaddress in a url it gives me the apache2 default page.
What else do I need to change for staging.domain.com to be the default url for this server?
Please forgive my ignorance here as I've never looked at Ruby on Rails before.

Comment: Don't think this isn't a ruby-on-rails issue. Sounds like a DNS issue. Are you sure you are touching the staging.domain.com server?  What do you get when you ping staging.domain.com?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. When I ping staging.domain.com I get the staging server ip address. It's like it's being redirected to domain.com.

Comment: Can you check the logs to see if it is actually hitting the server when you hit the website?

Comment: When I type in staging.domain.com internally, it redirects automatically, and the logs do not show that I am hitting the server. 
When I do it externally, it takes me to staging.domain.com.
Thanks! I think it is an internal DNS issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a DNS problem, that it wasn't taking me to staging.domain.com. I was able to resolve this by updating my local DNS.